# selected and focused states of UITabBarItem on tvOS

Tags: ios, uitabbar, tvos

How can I give tabBar items different titles colors for selected and focused states?

I am setting title text attributes but it does not make any difference between selected and focused states, I have always the same color.

Here is how I create tabBar Items:

```
   for title in titlesArray {

        let item = UITabBarItem(title: title, image: nil, selectedImage: nil)
        item.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 1)], for: .selected)
        item.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.2)], for: .normal)
        item.setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue], for: .focused)

        tabBarItems.append(item)
    }

    tabbar.items = tabBarItems
```

Can any one help me to understand how to achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if it can help in anyway :

For normal:

```
 UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.grayColor()], forState:.Normal)
```

and for selected :

```
   UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttribute([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.redColor()], forState:.Selected)
```

Comment: My question is: How can I give tabBar items different titles colors for selected and focused states? for normal and selected states what is did is already working.

Comment: Is this helpful in any way : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433009/how-to-change-tab-bar-item-text-colour-on-focus-in-tvos